# How to declare a custom type for a function parameter?

Tags: dart, types

I'd like to type my function parameters in order to get code complete for the possible values of the "method" parameter.

If I had to do this using Typescript, I would do something like this:

```
type MethodType = 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE'

const fetcher = async (method: MethodType) => {
  ...
}
```

Basically, I created a type containing some values and used it as a typing for the `method` argument.

How can I accomplish the same with Dart?

```
Future fetcher(String method = 'GET') async {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Please describe what that typescript code does so that those that don't know typescript can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, this sounds like the exact use case for an [`enum`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#enumerated-types).

Here is how you could use it, based on your example:

```
enum HttpMethod {
  GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
}

Future fetcher(HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.GET) async {
  // do stuff
}
```

Note: The [dart style guidelines](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#prefer-using-lowercamelcase-for-constant-names) recommend the use of `lowerCamelCase` for constants in new code, but I used `SCREAMING_CAPS` above to match your code and the actual HTTP method names.

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I was thinking of passing a `String` instead of an `HTTPMethod` enum as the method argument, like so: `fetcher(method: 'GET')` rather than `fetcher(method: HttpMethod.GET)`. Do you think that can be done?

Comment: You can't define a type to be just a specific set of values in Dart. That's what enums are for, not strings.

Comment: As @Irn said, you can't create custom types like that. If you cannot use enums for some reason (I don't know why; you can extend them with extension methods), you could do something weird like sub-class String for your needs. But in that case, you still might as well through an invalid argument exception or something similar (I cannot remember if Dart has an InvalidArgumentException--I have been dealing a lot with Java recently).

Comment: If you want to use a String because you want to be able to get the value as a String, you can do so with an extension method on the enum (can't remember if enum's support toString as you would expect).